# DBSet and dynamic sql expressions

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So I have Products class that represent the products table.
To get all the records I do:

```
db.Products.ToList()
```

And I have a string like this:

```
String queryString = "mp=5 AND optic=TRUE AND price=500";
```

My question is how can I use this string to filter Products? Where func only accept lambda expressions..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's still supported or not, but you can use Dynamic LINQ to allow you to add 'text' based expressions as you require. See:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx
- http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html

You may also want to think about using a Predicate builder to do the same job more declaratively. There are a few out there, but one that I've used with great success is the albahari one:

- http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

hope this helps..

Comment: I just saw .SqlQuery("string",object[]) - what about it?

Comment: never used it tbh, as i tend to use lambdas exclusively. however, found this which may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/adonetefx/thread/f0665ee1-9f49-4a7f-a750-c10a5d262110#75350997-896f-4d1f-bfe8-7f853323cd59. see also: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application  it's not a style i would ever chose to use mind you!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute Raw SQL against the DbSet and return a strong typed list. For detail, please refer to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/04/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-10-raw-sql-queries.aspx) by EF team.